# CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync

Tags: gsutil

```
.....
At destination listing 8360000...
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
.....
I tried to locate the files with this sync problem but I am not able to do so. Is there a "skip error" option of is there a way I can have gsutil more verbose?

My command line is like this:

gsutil -V -m rsync -d -r -U -P -C -e -x  -x 'Download/*' /opt/ gs://mybucket1/kraanloos/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have created a script to split the problem. This gives me more info for a solution


!#/bin/bash
array=(
3ware
AirTime
Amsterdam
BigAirBag
Download
guide
home
Install
Holding
Multimedia
newsite
Overig
Trak-r
)


for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo Processing : $i
    PROCESS="/usr/bin/gsutil -m rsync -d -r -U -P -C -e -x 'Backup/*' /opt/$i/ gs://mybucket1/kraanloos/$i/"
    echo $PROCESS
    $PROCESS
    echo ""
    echo ""
done
```